# Calling JSON from a php file to a HTML page

Tags: php, html, json

I'm making a html page that needs to show a video.The URL of the video is found in a `jsondecode` output. Is here any way to pick pieces from that `JSON` output and use it in my html page? I have tried POST and GET and echo but it doesn't seem to work.

*To be clear: I'm trying to get it from a php file to a separate HTML file.*

The `JSON` response is in a separate file in a function.

```
public function getURL(){
    $server_url= ilObjPresentations2GoGUI::getServerUrl();
     $secret_key= ilObjPresentations2GoGUI::getSecretKey();
     $authorized_group= ilObjPresentations2GoGUI::getAuthorizedGroup();
     $link_usable= ilObjPresentations2GoGUI::getLinkUsable();
     $query = 'technology';

    $date = new DateTime('NOW');
    $ts = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
    $interval = 'PT' . $this->link_usable . 'H';
    $date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $link_usable . 'H'));
    $expired = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
    $url = $server_url . '?action=search&query='. $query . '&group='. $authorized_group . '&ts=' . $ts . '&expired=' .$expired; 

    $token = ilObjPresentations2GoAPI::create($url,$secret_key);
    $goodurl = $url . '&token=' . $token;

    $json = file_get_contents($goodurl);
    $the_data = json_decode($json, true);}
```

Output:

```
array(9) { ["schemaVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["catalogueVersion"]=> string(14) "4.0.5651.20898" ["encoding"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" ["action"]=> string(6) "search" ["query"]=> string(10) "technology" ["page"]=> string(1) "1" ["pageCount"]=> string(1) "1" ["success"]=> string(4) "true" ["response"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(6) "bWKUL2" ["title"]=> string(57) "Technology-Based Professional Learning and Support Models" ["date"]=> string(19) "2011-12-05T10:19:21" ["contributors"]=> string(0) "" ["thumbnailUrl"]=> string(409) "https://DEMO-FORMS.presentations2go.eu/P2G/plugins/mediaservice.aspx?
```

(this is not all, but otherwise it would have been half a page)

Comment: What's the output from `var_dump($the_data);` after `json_decode`?

Comment: @unixarmy I edited the question with that data.

Comment: You can use `$the_data` to get values out of that json data. `$the_data['title']` for example.

Comment: @redelschaap How do you use that in HTML? How do I make the link between those two?

Comment: I've posted that as an answer

Comment: Can you let me know if that works for you?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the data within your JSON decoded array within your html, as long those files have a .php extension or they're included by PHP:

```
<div><?php echo $the_data['title']; ?></div>
```

Since your `$the_data` array is within the method `getURL()`, you could return the URL that's inside the `$the_data` array:

```
public function getURL() {
    ...

    $the_data = json_decode($json, true);

    return !empty($the_data['url']) ? $the_data['url'] : '';
}

...

<div><?php echo $your_object->getURL(); ?></div>
```

Comment: What if I need to do this for multiple video's?

Comment: That depends on how you get the urls for multiple video's. Are they all in one JSON object? Or in multiple objects?